# Получить название дня недели по его номеру

Tags: r

Пытаюсь создать функцию, которая по переданному параметру N возвращает наименование дня недели на английском языке, причём в качестве параметра N может быть вектор с набором значений произвольной длины.

```
days_of_the_weeks<-function(N){
english<-c('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday', 'Thursday','Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday')
l<-c(:)
for (english in l) {
z<-english[c(x=l)]
}
return (z)
}
print(days_of_the_weeks( c(3,5,7,8,2)))
```

Comment: и в чём состоит ваш вопрос? подсказка: monday — это понедельник.

Comment: Вопрос, состоит в следующем: необходимо создать функцию,которая по переданному параметру N возвращает наименование дня недели на английском языке(в нашем случаи), в вопросе ошибся.В качестве параметра N передавать вектор с набором значений произвольной длины.Главное, это условие, что вместо N, можно было передавать ни одно значение( N=5), а вектор(N<-c(3,7,8,4)) и выводилось: 3-Thursday, 7-Sunday и.т.д.

Comment: ну, создать — это замечательно. вопрос-то у вас в чём заключается? или вы сайтом ошиблись и вам надо было обратиться на биржу фриланса? // дополнить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот вы создали вектор:

```r
english<-c('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday', 'Thursday','Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday')
```

к элементам вектора можно обратиться по их индексу:

```r
english[1]
#> [1] "Monday"
```

но и индекс тоже может быть не скалярным значением, а вектором:

```r
english[c(3,5,2)]
#> [1] "Wednesday" "Friday"    "Tuesday"
```

или, без дополнительных промежуточных переменных:

```r
c('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday', 'Thursday','Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday')[c(3,5,2)]
#> [1] "Wednesday" "Friday"    "Tuesday"
```

получили уже практически функцию. осталось добавить синтаксическую обёртку:

```r
функция <- function(вектор) c('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday', 'Thursday','Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday')[вектор]
```

проверяем:

```r
функция(c(3,5,2))
#> [1] "Wednesday" "Friday"    "Tuesday"
функция(7)
#> [1] "Sunday"
```

---

но нет предела совершенству! а как быть с числами, большими семи? первое, что приходит в голову — взять остаток (оператор `%%`) от деления на семь. но ведь остаток от деления, например 7 на 7 — это будет 0, а не 7, как нам хотелось бы. а можно провернуть такой математический финт: сначала уменьшить число на единицу, получить остаток от деления на семь, а потом вновь добавить единицу. главное — в языке *r* все эти манипуляции работают одинаково хорошо как со скалярными величинами, так и с векторами («под капотом» скалярное значение — это просто вектор единичной длины):

```r
функция2 <- function(вектор) c('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday', 'Thursday','Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday')[(вектор-1)%%7+1]
```

проверяем. отлично работает даже и с отрицательными значениями:

```r
функция2(-10:10)
#>  [1] "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Saturday"  "Sunday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"  
#>  [7] "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Saturday"  "Sunday"    "Monday"   
#> [13] "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Saturday"  "Sunday"   
#> [19] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>